# Android getting Incompatible Types. Required java.lang.String Found int

Tags: java, android

I am getting

```
Incompatible Types. Required java.lang.String Found int
```

here is what i am using:

```
private String[] items = {R.string.name_1, R.string.name_2};
```

and then i would like to make something like this:

```
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                strName = items[which];

                if(strName.equalsIgnoreCase(R.string.name_1))
                {
                    // call activity
                }
                ....
          }
```

**Updated** as suggested by @Eran

```
          private String[] items = {
            getResources().getString(R.string.name_1),
            getResources().getString(R.string.name_2)
          };

          builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                strName = items[which];             
                if(strName.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.name_1)))
                {
                    // call activity
                }
                .......
            }
```

Still facing issue as shown below, **FYI** i am not using English as String

Log says:

`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:81) at com.lingual.game.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:46)`

Comment: which is line no. 46 in MainActivity ?? does it "if(strName.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.name_1)))"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`R.string.name_1` is an `int` identifier referring to a `String` resource, to you can't compare it to a `String`. To get the `String` it refers to you need to write `getResources().getString(R.string.name_1)`.

Therefore

```
if(strName.equalsIgnoreCase(R.string.name_1))
```

should be

```
if(strName.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.name_1)))
```

Similarly

```
private String[] items = {R.string.name_1, R.string.name_2};
```

should be

```
private String[] items = {getResources().getString(R.string.name_1), getResources().getString(R.string.name_2)};
```

EDIT:

Based on the following exception you got, it looks like this code appears in the constructor of your activity class, when the activity is not initialized yet. You should move it to `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`.

Comment: getting: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:81)
            at com.lingual.game.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:46)  check updated code as suggested by you, i am not using English as String ....

Comment: yes Eran i am using see updated code.. but still facing issue

Comment: @Sun which line is line 46 is MainActivity? Is it the if statement?

Comment: @Sun It looks like this code appears in the constructor of your class, when the Activity is not initialized yet. You should move it to onCreate().

Answer (score 2):

R is all integer values. You need to use

```
getResources().getString(R.string.value);
```

And if you want to store the integers and retrieve the Strings on the fly, use

```
private int[] items = {R.string.x ..., R.string.z);
```

and use

```
getResources().getString(items[i])
```

Answer (score 2):

For array of strings, create a string array in `strings.xml`, for ex:,

```
<string-array name="my_string_array">
    <item>Name1</item>
    <item>Name2</item>
    <item>Name3</item>        
</string-array>
```

And then assign it to your variable like this,

```
String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.my_string_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using R.string.key returns the resource id from the given key.

You should use

```
private String[] items = {getResources().getString(R.string.name_1), getResources().getString(R.string.name_2)};
```